# Error rxjs_Observable__.Observable.forkJoin is not a function?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, rxjs5, fork-join

I am using `Rxjs` in an `angualr-cli` application.

in viewer.component.ts

```
    //Other Imports
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    //omitting for brevity
   export class ViewerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    someFunction(someArg){
    //omitting for brevity
    let someArray: any = [];
    //Add some info
    Observable.forkJoin(someArray).subscribe(data => {
              //Do something with data
            });
    }
    //omitting for brevity
    }
```

I get and error as

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.Observable.forkJoin is not a function
    at ViewerComponent.webpackJsonp../src/app/component/viewer.component.ts.ViewerComponent.someFunction(http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:4022:73)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:3951:31
```

But if I Import `Rxjs` completely (`import 'rxjs';`) everything works. No error.
I cont seem to understand whats additional that needed.
I also tries importing `rxjs/Observable/forkjoin` but nothing to avail.

Any pointers on how to go about this.

Comment: what do you mean by import completly?

Comment: I have updated the question. 
Completely means `import 'rxjs';`

Comment: what is someArray ? what it contains ?

Comment: don't import whole lib, import necessary pieces instead

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS#es6-via-npm), you have two options:

1. Either import all operators as a single package
2. Or import each operator individually

In the first case you would use import like this:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

Rx.Observable.forkJoin(1,2,3)
```

In the second like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

I believe what you're looking for is the second option.

Comment: Thank Maximus, I think best practice is the 2nd option?

Comment: Thanks, Worked like charm :)

Comment: The first option was the solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For `RxJS v6.5+`, it is now:

`import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';`

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the forkJoin Operator as a function by importing forkJoin  instead of importing Observable.
Use **forkJoin.subscribe()** in place of **Observable.forkJoin.subscribe()**

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin'

export class ViewerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    someFunction(someArg){
      let someArray: any = [];
      forkJoin(someArray).subscribe(data => {
      });
    }
}
```

Source Code : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/forkJoin.ts

Answer (score 0):

In one project I used the following forkjoin code to upload images, it works perfectly.

```
/**
       *  Upload multiple image and then update the feature
       */
      public uploadImages(apiParams: any[], imageItems: any[]): Observable<any> {
        if (imageItems.length === 0) return;

        let promises = [];
        for (let imageItem of imageItems) {
          promises.push(this.uploadImage(apiParams, imageItem));
        }
        return Observable.forkJoin(...promises);
      }

      /**
       * upload single image
       */
      public uploadImage(apiParams: any[], imageItem: any): any {
        let _formData = new FormData();
        _formData.append("UploadedImage", imageItem,  (new Guid()).toString()+'.png');
        const imageApiUrl = StringFormatter.format(imagePoints.create, apiParams);
        return Observable.fromPromise(
          fetch(imageApiUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            body: _formData
          })
          .then(result => result.json())
        );
      }
```