# Importing forkJoin but still getting "not a function"

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm importing `forkJoin` as

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

but I'm still getting an error in my console:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_Observable__.a.forkJoin is not a function
```

I don't get this error in the Angular CLI compiler (using `ng serve`) nor does VS Code complain. Is there a different method of running forkJoin now? I'm running the latest build of Angular (5.*), with RxJS 5.5.*.

As requested, it's being called as thus:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    this.eventService.getTypes().first(),
    this.eventService.getDates().first()
).pipe(
```

Comment: what version of rxjs you are using?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Sorry, you're right, that's more relevant. My package.json is set to ^5.5.2, though not positive of the actual subversion.

Comment: Sorry, that was a case of typo in typing the code in. In hindsight, don't know why I typed it instead of copying it.

Comment: are you saying you don't get this error with @angular/cli, but using webpack, you do?

Comment: The error does not appear in the Angular CLI output, but does show up in the Chrome dev tools. I'm not doing any independent builds; it's all through ngCLI.

Comment: Can you show us how you call the forkJoin please ?

Comment: See this, [Error rxjs_Observable__.Observable.forkJoin is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743823/error-rxjs-observable-observable-forkjoin-is-not-a-function). Silly question are you first importing `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`?

Comment: @NoémiSalaün @RichardMatsen Yup, importing `Observable`, and sure, I'll throw in how it's being called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With RxJS 5.5 you should use it as a function. I'm not sure if Angular CLI 1.5 and newer are even configured to use the older prototype patching style of RxJS.

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin'

...

forkJoin(...).pipe(...).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot. It still feels weird using some of the methods as functions of their own, like `range`. It's so generic, having the Observable namespace feels more appropriate.

Comment: That's just the recommended way of using RxJS since 5.5.